# Python 3.7, split set into groups but have a minimum group size

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im looking for an efficient way to write a piece of code.

I am making a bot that pairs people off in groups of 4. Everyone signs up (its a discord bot, but that should not effect this portion of the application) by reacting to a message, then the bot takes them and splits them into groups of 4.

But what does the bot do if there are a number of people not divisible by 4?
What I'm looking to do is not allow any less than a group of 3.

12 people = 3 groups of 4

13 people = 3 groups of 3, 1 group of 4

14 people = 2 groups of 3, 2 groups of 4

Does Python have an easy way to do this type of math?

I also am not sure if there is a more efficient way of saying what Im trying to say. If someone is aware of a particular search term I could use, that would be helpful too.

Comment: This isn't a language question.  It's an algorithm question, or a basic math question.  For n = 1, 2, or 5 there is no solution.  Otherwise you just need to solve the diophantine equation 3*a + 4*b = n.  You can start with n % 4, then keep adding 4 until the result is a multiple of 3.  You'll need to add either 0, 4, or 8.  No more will bee needed.

Comment: Does the order in the lists matter or just the lists sizes?

Comment: the order does matter. For more context, I am working on a pairing system for a variant of the game Magic The Gathering called Commander. Its typically played in groups of 4, but can be played in groups of 3 in a pinch. Its not good in groups of 2 and obviously not 1. So I'm taking a list of people who reacted to a comment, randomizing the list, then trying to split it into as many groups of 4 as I can, but then any necessary number of groups of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign players from a shuffled list to groups of 4 or 3, you can use `playerindex % #of_groups'

```py
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from math import ceil

# parameters
num_players = 15
groupsize = 4
max_group = ceil(num_players / groupsize)

# Setting up test data
player = list(range(num_players)) # player represented by id
random.shuffle(player)
d = defaultdict(list)

# the 'algorithm'
for i,e in enumerate(player):
    d[i % max_group].append(e)

print(list(d.values())) # desired groups as lists of player ids
```

Out:

```
[[5, 4, 6, 11], [12, 8, 0, 7], [14, 3, 2, 13], [9, 10, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `divide` from [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/):

```
from more_itertools import divide

a_list = [range(12), range(13), range(14), range(15), range(16)]

for i in a_list:
    divisor = len(i) // 4
    if len(i) % 4 == 0:
        print([list(j) for j in divide(divisor, i)])
    else:
        print([list(j) for j in divide(4, i)])
```

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: This looks super promising. Is there a way to do this in Python 3.7? I get the error that Python 3 does not support assignment expressions.

Comment: @Sugitime I have removed the ```assignment expression``` which is not available in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple modulo and integer division math will you get you started.  Assuming there are `total_people`...

The number of groups of four could be found by

```
n_full_groups = total_people // 4 # integer division
```

The remainder can be found with the `%` operator

```
n_left_over = total_people % 4
```

Now you mentioned a requirement to have at least 3 people per group.  if `n_left_over` equals `3` or `0` you're done.

If `n_left_over` equals `1` or `2` you would simply subtract one person from one or two of the "full groups" we found above